# My activity is going to potentially hold a lot of fragments (5+) how should I create them?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Should I create member variables of each fragments in my activity?

Like:

```
private DemoFragment1 frag1;
private DemoFragment2 frag2;
private DemoFragment3 frag3;
private DemoFragment4 frag4;
private DemoFragment5 frag5;
```

and then in the Activity.onCreate() should I instantiate all of them so that I know they have all been started and only been started once? Or when I go to create them should I do it like this?

```
createFrag1(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_holder, new DemoFragment1());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Check out the answer below. I do this when fragments have extreme graphics etc. to optimize the time to load and animate the fragments. Replace will to a good job of handling fragments without having to call add then remove on the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my activities, I add all the fragments onWindowFocusChanged (so I have proper screen measurements):

```
 private void addFragments() {
    if(mPassedMachine.getMachineType() == MachineType.ZR7)
        addZeroFragment(ANIMATION_TYPE_NONE, false);
    else 
        addLevelFragment(ANIMATION_TYPE_NONE, false);
    addHeartRateFragment(ANIMATION_TYPE_NONE, false);
    addMaxMinAvgFragment(ANIMATION_TYPE_NONE, false);
    addExtraFragment(ANIMATION_TYPE_NONE, false);
 }
```

When I add the fragment, I make sure to add it to the fragment stack. Then when I retrieve the fragment, I either get the existing one, or create a new one:

```
 private void addLevelFragment(int animationType, boolean shouldShow) {
    String fragmentTag = getFragmentTag();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentTransactionWithAnimation(animationType);
    mLevelFragment = (SupplementLevelFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

    if(mLevelFragment == null) {
        mLevelFragment = new SupplementLevelFragment();
        Bundle levelBundle = getSupplementBundle(false);
        levelBundle.putBoolean(WorkoutSupplementBaseFragment.SUPPLEMENT_CLOCK_COUNT_DOWN, mTimerCountingDown);
        levelBundle.putInt(WorkoutSupplementBaseFragment.FRAGMENT_ORIGINAL_TIME, mTotalMinutes);
        levelBundle.putInt(SupplementLevelFragment.FRAGMENT_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);
        mLevelFragment.setArguments(levelBundle);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.workout_supplement_fragment_middle_layout, mLevelFragment, fragmentTag);

    if(shouldShow == true) 
        fragmentTransaction.show(mLevelFragment);
    else
        fragmentTransaction.hide(mLevelFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentTransaction = null;
}
```

I do this because I scroll through the fragments and add data to them even if they currently do not have focus.